# Voice recording fading on the attack

Tags: recording, software, cubase

I started to record my voice but I've noticed that it is faded on the attack. Do you know how to cope with that?

Here is my voice recording (starts at 00:25). https://voca.ro/5fzFZKZz08p

I'm using Cubase Le with a PGA48 mic from Shure

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "faded" ? It sound more like "intermittent" to me. Absolutely no way to guess what that might be. Start by checking your connections & see if the input level looks constant on both your pre-amp & in Cubase, to even hope to start to isolate the issue.

Comment: It sounds like you're moving away from the mic. Maybe turning your head, or lifting or lowering your chin.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tetsujin already mentioned in the comments, there are many possibilities what could cause the problem.

If the input level looks constant on both your pre-amp and in cubase, you can try to deactivate any plugins on your track.

I am by far no expert, but to me it sound like there is a gate or something similar which is badly configured for the input signal. You can hear the vocals come up too late and if they get more quite you can hear the release dial down the volume.

Comment: Just reading the description of the problem, without listening to the track, my first thought was an aggressive gate also.

Comment: Not too many possibilities I think!   It has to be a noise gate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that your voice is NOT fading in any way ON or after the attack  at least not due to an electrical issue.

What I do hear is the following.  You voice does not sound supported after the phrase is complete.  In other words you are stopping.  That might be what you want.  For some phrases it sounds like you are holding a note after the word is sung but not pushing more air through.  This will sound faded and the only way to avoid that is to push more air through at constant pressure.  On some phrases your voice is staccato so there is no reason to expect a sustained note.  It sounded to me in one or two instances that you may have moved your head away from the mic during a phrase.  I suppose this could have been electrical too but it really sounded like your head was moving.  If you are trying to record yourself in a studio you want to avoid this.

If you think you have a problem with the sound not being at peak on the attack then I'd ask if you are using software to record yourself or mixing this down onto a disk.  I'd assume the former as almost no one uses tape or other physical media anymore.  The process can degrade sound quality.  Also, many microphones and audio platforms have a voice activated option in them.  They only start responding when the first impulse is detected.  This can be annoying and lead to a ramped up voice rather than a hard start and if you are saying something with a hard consonant in the beginning that can be missed.  If this is the case you should be able to find that out by reading the specs for the mic and recording s/w.  Hopefully that can be turned off.  But in my opinion I did not hear that.